# Getting JSON data from deferred call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, apply, deferred

I feel like I'm missing something completely simple.  Please help!  My first time using this part of jQuery....

Here is my code. How can I loop through each element returned by `do_it`?

```
function do_it(a){
  return $.getJSON('url', {mode: 'get_array', id: a}); // returns JSON object
};

$.when.apply(do_it[1,2,3]).then (function(data){
  // how to get each element returned by do_it() here?
}, function () {console.log('Failed');<br>});
```

Comment: Sorry,my typo.  That's what I have in my code....Fixed.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: There are many strange things going on here. Could you please provide a detailed description in plain English of exactly what it is you’re trying to do?

Comment: `do_it[1,2,3]`, shouldn't this be `do_it([1,2,3])` ?

Comment: {"ID":1,"L_Name":"Jones","F_Name":"Jan","Email":"jjones@email.com","Telephone_No":"xxx.xxx.xxxx","Institution":"IT","Department":"3","Notes":"","Secretary":0}{"ID":3,"L_Name":"Smith","F_Name":"Christopher","Email":"email@gmail.com","Telephone_No":"","Institution":"IT","Department":"18","Notes":"","Secretary":0}{"ID":4,"L_Name":"White","F_Name":"Amanda","Email":"white@email.com","Telephone_No":"","Institution":"UT","Department":"25","Notes":"","Secretary":0}

Comment: hahaha, I don't think that is what @JezenThomas meant :/

Comment: Is this request actually working for you?  There seems to be alot of strange things in your code like a `<br>` tag inside your JavaScript.

Comment: I'm trying to wait for the first JSON call to finish so that I can manipulate some of what I get before making another getJSON call (which I will chain, but there's no point in detailing that code until I can get something useful from this one.  I'm finding my usual nesting of getJSON calls isn't allowing me to do this.  It seemed that using $.when and $.apply would be a good start.  (Anyway, it's code I'd like to learn how to use....)

Comment: That JSON as you've printed it doesn't parse.

Comment: Phil-- I was responding to Andy. All the html tags in here are the result of my trying to use STACKOVERFLOW for the first time.  Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: @user135650 If you’d like to wait for the first request to finish before starting the second request, then you’re making *synchronous* requests. The jQuery `.when()` method is for managing concurrency, *i.e.*, requests you make *asynchronously*.

I think you’re using the wrong tool for the job, and you need to review your approach.

Comment: Andy: I cut and pasted it from Firebug's console, though I did edit out the particulars and may have screwed something up there.  It works for me and I can parse it nicely if I don't use the $.when method.

Comment: Jezen-- OK I'll buy that, but there must be some way of accessing what's being returned there.. I was able to do it when I was only sending one variable and only getting one object element back using $.when; it failed, however, when I started sending an array, which is why I started using $.apply.  The code all works without errors, but I can't see what the original call is returning when it's a complex object.... Does that make sense?  --Nat

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` returns a promise object: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/
With that, you can attach `done`, `fail` and `always` functions to run respectively.  Using that, you can then format your code as.

```
function do_it (id) {
    return $.getJSON(url, {
        mode: 'get_array',
        id: id
    });
}

do_it([1, 2, 3]).done(function (data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        console.log(key, " = ", data[key]);
    }
}).fail(function () {
    console.log("Failed");
});
```

I'm not sure what you intended to pass to `do_it` if it was the array or each `id` separately, if the latter, you can do:

```
$.each([1, 2, 3], function (id) {
   do_it(id) // same stuff as above
```

**Edit**: Based on your comments, here is a suggestion, albeit not the best performing suggestion.

```
var data = [];

$.when.apply($.map([1,2,3], function (id) {
    return do_it(id).done(function (d) {
        data.push(d[0]);
    });
}).done(function () {
    for (var d in data) {
        console.log(d);
    }
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("Failed");
});
```

Comment: The problem is, in spite of getting a getJSON return, nothing is appearing in "data", so this fails.  I'm sending an array to a php program and getting a JSON response.  Data shows up when there's one element in the array (and a single JSON object), but not when I get a complex JSON object back after sending a multi-element array...

Comment: Do you have a live demo of this where individuals can see?  What qualifies to you as a complex JSON object.  Are you sure that id is supposed to be an array and not just one id (e.g. the one array element).  It sounds like that's the case.

Comment: Sorry about my terminology: what I mean by complex object is an encoded associative array.  The php creates an associative array for each id, then json_encodes the whole array and sends it back.  When there's only one id there's only one line in the array before it's encoded (and I get to it via data[0]), when there're more lines then I can't get to it.  So it looks like I'm going to have to return data differently or find another way at parsing it.

Comment: You could try `$.parseJSON` (`jQuery.parseJSON`), but if it's being returned as in the comments in your post where you have `{"ID":....}{"ID":....}` not in an error, it's going to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I've fixed any errors in the data and used a `deferred` object to copy the functionality of your program.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/kXk6V/).

`data` is an array containing a number of objects. The code loops through the array objects and picks out values from each to add to a table. Note that I tend to use `array.join()` instead of string concatenation to build up HTML - YMMV.

```
$.when(do_it()).then(function (data) {
    var html = [];
    html.push('<table>');
    for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
      var row = [];
      row.push('<tr>');
      row.push('<td>' + data[i].ID + '</td>');
      row.push('<td>' + data[i].L_Name + '</td>');
      row.push('<td>' + data[i].F_Name + '</td>');
      row.push('<td>' + data[i].Email + '</td>');
      row.push('<td>' + data[i].Department + '</td>');
      row.push('</tr>');
      html.push(row.join(''));
    }
    html.push('</table>');
});
```

I hope it's of some use to you.

Comment: Tried this: data[i].L_Name comes up undefined, as does data[i].

Comment: `L_Name` was one of the things I had to fix in the JSON you posted. It might have something to do with that underscore. Are you getting any data back at all?

Comment: I'm getting the JSON object listed (with some typos apparently) in the first response.  If I send only one array element and get back a simple JSON object I can parse that, but when I send an array and get back a complex JSON object data comes up undefined no matter how I've tried -- and I've tried! -- to parse it...gaaah

Comment: So if you do `do_it(1)` you're getting something you can parse back, but you do `do_it([1,2,3])` you don't?

Comment: Right! --or, actually, do_it([1]) vs. do_it([1,2,3])

Comment: Actually, do_it([1]) -> data.ID works while do_it([1,2]) -> data.ID & data[0].ID both = undefined, even though I've successfully received the ajax response.

Comment: Can you post the ajax response for each case in a jsfiddle for me to look at?

Comment: Andy-- As it turns out my json was ill-formed.  It turns out I'd been looking at an old version of the program and as soon as I looked at the current version I saw what was wrong and fixed it. Gaah! Thanks for your efforts.  --Nat

Comment: @user135650, no problem. I was thinking about it on the way home :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the returned value is an array:

```
$.when.apply(do_it[1,2,3]).then(function(data){
   $(JSON.parse.(data)).each(function(index, element){
   //do stuff
   });
}, function () {console.log('Failed');<br>});
```

EDIT:

From your comments, lets assume:

```
var data = '[{"ID":1,"L_Name":"Jones","F_Name":"Jan","Email":"jjones@email.com","Telephone_No‌​":"xxx.xxx.xxxx","Institution":"IT","Department":"3","Notes":"","Secretary":0},{"I‌​D":3,"L_Name":"Smith","F_Name":"Christopher","Email":"email@gmail.com","Telephone‌​_No":"","Institution":"IT","Department":"18","Notes":"","Secretary":0},{"ID":4,"L_‌​Name":"White","F_Name":"Amanda","Email":"white@email.com","Telephone_No":"","Inst‌​itution":"UT","Department":"25","Notes":"","Secretary":0}]';
```

Notice i added the opening and closing brackets for the array [ ... ] and the commas between elements.

Then to loop through the array you could do:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
$(json).each(function(index,element){
    //do stuff
    alert("index: " + index + " element: " + element );
});
```

Comment: I think there's an extra dot between "parse" and the open paren.  But it doesn't work with the arrayed JSON I'm getting back.

Comment: I think your response is malformed; in the example you provided the opening and closing brackets were missing, and commas between array elements.